# General approach to factoring

Tags: polynomials

I had to factor the following : $(x^2−12x+36)$

This is obviously $(x−6)^2$, but if the given term is not in such an obvious form, what is a general approach to do this?

Such as:

$x^2+3x−28$ is equal to $(x−4)(x+7)$, but how do you get to this?

Maybe try some values and run away if they don't match?

Comment: If the leading coefficient is $1$, and you want to factor $x^2 + bx + c$, then look for numbers that add to $b$ and multiply to $c$; so $-4$ and $7$ add to $3$, while multiplying to $-28$. (Also, the first example you gave isn't correct).

Comment: As to the question, you can use the [Quadratic Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) for the general case.

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers, these are exact what i was looking for. Also edited the first polynom.

Comment: [Complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), or apply the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), which is derived by completing the square for the general equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Comment: It takes about couple of weeks of practicing by solving several dozens of quadratic equations, to have an eye on this kind of things. At least, that's how I learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the quadratic equation to solve $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then you get
$$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Then, the fatorization of $ax^2+bx+c$ is
$$ax^2+bx+c=\left(x+\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}-b}{2a}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)$$
Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, now i see it, thanks

Comment: @BastiFunck Sure!